# Does a laser's listed wattage or joules include the frequency? Or just the amplitude?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

In other words, if the number of photons in two different lasers is the same, but the second laser has a higher wavelength, does the second one have more 'wattage' or more total joules?
(Since higher-frequency photons are more energetic?

Comment: Typically it is specced for power or J/pulse at one or more frequencies.